# Preventing Mathematica from considering small values to be equal to zero

Tags: machine-precision, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

In my calculations I have a variable (say `z`) which can be an argument of `Log`, say, `z Log[z]`.

Under some conditions, `z = x-y`, where:

```
x = a + c; 
y = b + c;
a = 4.24835*10^-18;
b = -4.24835*10^-18;
c = 1.3956*10^18;
```

By default Mathematica considers both

```
4.24835*10^-18 == -4.24835*10^-18 == 0
```

and this leads to `x = y = 1.3956*10^18` and, hence, `z = 0` and `z Log[z] = Indeterminate`.

How can I prevent this and make sure it does not happen elsewhere?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Use extended precision numbers instead of machine numbers.

Comment: please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Use extended precision numbers instead of machine numbers. Machine numbers have a precision of about 16, so subtracting a number 36 orders of magnitude smaller will not cause a change. For example:

```
b = 4.24835`10*^-18 - 1.3956`50*^18;
c = -4.24835`10*^-18 - 1.3956`50*^18;

b-c
```

> 8.496700000*10^-18

The back ticks `` ` `` are used to specify the precision to use. Also, it's simpler to use `*^-18` instead of `* 10^-18`, as this creates the desired number directly without having to multiply the mantissa by a power of 10.

Comment: please see the edit